# laravel 5.1 authserviceprovider define a permission

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

Trying to sort out this new AuthServiceProvider in Laravel 5.1.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);

    $gate->define('test-permission', function ($user) {
        return true;
    });

}
```

In my blade I try

```
@if (Gate::allows('test-permission'))
    hello world.
@endif
```

I get no love. If I change it to `Gate::denies('test-permission')` the hello world renders.

Ultimate I want to pull my permissions from my Entrust data to migrate my permissions to a Laravel 5.1 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel will only call your closure if there's a logged-in user.

If there's no logged-in user, Laravel will always deny everything.

---

If you *are* logged in, chances are you haven't [properly registered](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6722b10/config/app.php#L144) the `AuthServiceProvider`.

Comment: I am logged in - but perhaps I need to make a change to my authentication to make it 5.1 compatible. I followed the instructions. I dd(Auth::user()) and it looks good. Also if (Auth::check()) returns true.

Comment: Try `dd`ing in your `define` callback. Is it reached at all?

Comment: Nope - dd anywhere in AuthServiceProvider does nothing

Comment: Are you sure it's actually registered in `config/app.php`'s `providers` array?

Comment: Like so:   'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',

Comment: That's wrong. It should be `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`

Comment: Thanks Joseph - you have me on the right track now - not sure how/where I missed that - maybe was an upgrade step. If you want to post that as an answer I'll check it as the right one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97004/discussion-between-dylan-glockler-and-joseph-silber).